# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api' ...while importing tpot

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, tpot

```
File "C:\Users\Pulkit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tpot\base.py", line 79, in <module>
    import win32api ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Even after installing pypiwin32 via pip... I am getting this error  when I am importing the tpot module. I am  currently 
 using python 3.6.3...

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed by chance? What do you get when you enter "which python" and "which pip" in the command line?

Comment: 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking for **pywin32** not *win32api*

Download the appropriate **pywin32** for your from [GitHub](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) 
Install the exe.

***ex :***  **pywin32-223.win-amd64-py3.6.exe** is for 64 bit Python 3.6

Add pywin32 as a dependency for windows users.

After this it should solve the problem

Reference GitHub issue : [Tpot issue 333](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/333)